# Select fews columns (DTO) with specification JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa version 1.5.1.RELEASE .

My domain is :

```
public class MyDomain{
....
....
private String prop1;
private String prop2;
......
......
}
```

My JPA Specification is:

```
public final class MyDomainSpecs {

public static Specification<MyDomain> search(final String prop1,final String prop2) {

    return new Specification<MyDomain>() {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyDomain> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            // Some tests if prop1 exist .....
            Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(root.get("prop1"), prop1);
            Predicate predicate2 = cb.equal(root.get("prop2"), prop2);
            return cb.and(predicate1, predicate2);
        }

    };
}
```

}

My Repository :

```
public interface MyDomainRepository extends JpaRepository<MyDomain, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyDomain> {
List<MyDomain> findAll(Specification<MyDomain> spec);
}
```

All is Working . 
But my need (For performance DB tunning) is to not return and select all fields of MyDomain from DB .

I need to select only for example tree properties (prop1, prop2, prop3) , idealy in a DTO Object .

I don't want to convert My `List<MyDomain>` to `List<MyDto>` because i am tunning DB request .

So , I don't find any way to do that with spring-data-Jpa and Specification .

Any Idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as for now. There is a ticket for this but no idea if it will be ever implmented: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-51

Answer (score 0):

Create a special version of `MyDomain` (e.g. `MyDomainSummary` or `LightMyDomain`) that only includes the fields you want to map.

**Basic example**

Borrowed from the excellent [JPA WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Example_of_basic_mapping_annotations).

Assume a JPA entity (i.e. domain class) like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class BasicEmployee {
  @Column(name="ID")
  private long id;       

  @Column(name="F_NAME")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name="L_NAME")
  private String lastName;

  // Any un-mapped field will be automatically mapped as basic and column name defaulted.
  private BigDecimal salary;  
}
```

The SQL query generated will be similar to

```
SELECT ID, F_NAME, L_NAME, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEE
```

if no conditions (`where` clause) are defined. So, to generalize the basic case one can say that the number of queried columns is equal to the number of mapped fields in your entity. Therefore, the fewer fields your entity, the fewer columns included in the SQL query.

You can have an `Employee` entity with e.g. 20 fields and a `BasicEmployee` as above with only 4 fields. Then you create different repositories or different repository methods for both.

**Performance considerations**

However, I seriously doubt you'll see noticeable performance improvements unless the fields you want to omit represent relationships to other entities. Before you start tweaking here log the SQL that is currently issued against the data base, then remove the columns you want to omit from that SQL, run it again and analyze what you gained.

Comment: My question was not about Performance , There is an Performance Audit that indicate in our context we need to remove the select * . For your response can you provide more details , this is not clear at all . I need a solution based on Spring-DATA-JPA and specification JPA .

Comment: `select *` queries are bad, that's true. However, I'd bet neither Spring Data JPA nor your JPA provider (Hibernate, EclipseLink, which ever it is) creates those, that'd very much surprise me. I'll provide an example for those unfamiliar with JPA.